# SQLite INSERT with ForeignKey from another table

Tags: sqlite, insert

I have thre tables: `Table1`, `Table2`, and `Table3`.

want to insert a record into `Table1`, 
then insert a row into `Table2` with a column containing the ID from `Table1`,
then insert a row into `Table3` also containing a column with the ID from `Table1`.

I am using SQLite with the Kompex C++ wrapper library.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [GetLastInsertRowId](http://sqlitewrapper.kompex-online.com/doxygen/class_kompex_1_1_s_q_lite_database.html#aed51e757cb836b8830cdb0a5aa5ca967) to get the ID of the most recently inserted record.